# Diverge of magnetic field and magnetic potential

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, calculus

I've come up with the following identity in a problem but don't know how to prove it. Can anyone help me out? Thanks

$$\nabla\cdot(\vec{B}\times\vec{A})=0$$

So far I've tried:

$$\nabla\cdot(\vec{B}\times\vec{A})=\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\times\vec{B}-\vec{B}\cdot\nabla\times\vec{A}=\mu\vec{A}\vec{j}-B^2$$

But I don't get anywhere with this.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I edited the entry

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that B is curl of A and you will get the result.And B is u times J only for magnetostatics not in general, so what you are trying is not always correct.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $B=\nabla \times A$ into $\nabla \times (B \times A)$ and use the identity for $\nabla \times A \times A = 0$, and you will prove your identity.